# SharedPreference or Map<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>

Tags: android

I have more than 10 images to be dynamically fetched from server when my app launches (mostly just the 1st time the app launches).

What is the best practice for doing this and why?

1. Maintain a  `Map<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>` where I will have a hashmap where the elements are SoftReference.
2. Saving `byte[]` using

```
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imgData, Base64.DEFAULT);
SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edit=shre.edit();
edit.putString("image_data",encodedImage);
edit.commit();
```

Can someone illustrate the advantage of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should use something like an Image Cache. For example, you can use the [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library. It will help you to optimize the memory usage of your app.

There are a lot of exapmles in the web, but basicaly everything comes down to one line of code:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

Also check out these links:

1. [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) - from Android Developers site
2. [Picaso Library](https://github.com/square/picasso) - from Square, that's where Jake Wharton works.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
Checking the caching mechanism.
But can you say, when we can use the option 2?
Will it be of any advantage in any case?

Comment: I don't think so. You see, there is a possibility the your code will cause a OutOFMemoryError. Especially if `imgData` will be large. Imagine the your 10 images are high quality, and your app will crash if it runs on low end device.

Comment: IMHO `SharedPreference` should be used to store some fast accessible data. Counters, Strings, etc.